Can I ask for when the meaning of three Arabic words changed in a single question or it is too broad?
I want to ask about the history of meaning change in three Arabic words.
I want to explain each word in one or two paragraph.
Can I ask it in a single question or it is considered too broad and encourages downvotes?

It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you want to ask - many etymology questions aren't considered on-topic here. You might as well just skip this step and ask the question directly.
